# character space of C*-algebra

Tags: c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I have a question about a passage in the book *C*-algebras and Operator Theory* by Murphy. On page 41, between theorems 2.1.9 and 2.1.10 he proves that the character space of a non-unital, non-zero, abelian C*-algebra $A$ is non-empty. The proof is as follows:

Let $A'$ be the unitization of $A$. $A$ contains a non-zero hermitian element $a$. Since $r(a)=\|a\|$. Then by theorem 2.1.1, it follows that there is a character $\tau$ on $A'$ such that $|\tau(a)|=\|a\|\neq0$. Then the restriction of $\tau$ to $A$ is a non-zero homomorphism from $A$ to $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. a character on $A$.

My question is: why does $r(a)=\|a\|$ imply that there exists a character $\tau$ such that $|\tau(a)|=\|a\|$? I konw $r(a)=\|\hat{a}\|_\infty$, where $\hat{a}$ is the Gelfand transform of $a$. This would imply the existence of a character $\tau_2$ such that $|\tau_2(a)|>r(a)-\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0$. But why equal to $r(a)$. Is this because $\sigma(a)=\hat{a}(\Omega(A'))$, and $\hat{a}$ is continuous and $\Omega(A')$ is compact since $A'$ is unital? (implying $\sigma(a)\subset\mathbb{C}$ is compact, hence closed)

Is the use of the unitization $A'$ really necessary here, or could the $\tau_2$ i suggesed above suffice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is one way to look at it. Here's another: even before the Gelfand transform, we already know from Lemma 1.2.4 that $\sigma(a)$ is compact. Here it is only proven for unital Banach algebras, but that is simply because Murphy only defines the spectrum of an element in a non-unital algebra on page 13, at the very end of section 1.2. (Think about it: how could we even define a spectrum if there is no unit?) Since $\sigma_{\tilde A}(a)$ is compact and we have $\sigma_A(a) = \sigma_{\tilde A}(a)$ by definition, we see that $\sigma_A(a)$ is also compact.

Now we use theorem 1.3.4. The image of the compact set $\sigma(a)$ under the continuous map $z \mapsto |z|$ is again compact, so the maximum is attained. (The maximum is of course equal to $r(a)$.) Also, the maximum does not arise from the extra $\{0\}$ we adjoined in theorem 1.3.4(2), since we have $r(a) = ||a|| > 0$. Thus, there is some $\tau \in \Omega(A)$ such that $|\tau(a)| = r(a)$ holds. Now we have $|\tau(a)| = r(a) = ||a||$, as desired.

I think this is essentially the same argument as the one you suggested. Most of the machinery that Murphy develops up to the Gelfand transform can again be derived as a consequence of the Gelfand transform.

---

As for your second question, it seems that the use of the unitisation is not *really* necessary, as both of our methods show. But then again, whenever you're talking about the spectrum of an element in a non-unital algebra, you're implictly using some information about its unitisation.